# I can't seem to run my python code in VS code

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, cmd, syntax-error

I'm a first year IT Student and relatively new to python and this is my first time using this HP laptop, running Windows 10 to code. I haven't encountered this problem before so I'm not sure what is wrong.

[First error message displayed, when clicking the little play button to run the code in VS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9pvH.jpg)

It seems to be some syntax error but I genuinely don't see anything wrong in my code. I tried again by writing "python (File Name)" and clicking enter and received another error message.

[Second error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z68qG.jpg)

The marked out parts are just my name and student number.

Answer (score 0):

## Short Answer:

[image: VS code cmd]

Fastest solution is to switch the vs code terminal from Powershell to Cmd.

On the drop-down there choose Cmd.

## Long Answer:

Just set the path in the powershell.

Open Powershell and run it as an admin.
Run this code: (copy, paste from here)
“

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "$env:Path;C:\Program Files\Python35-32")“
```

##### Note: Here, in Path, add the path where you’ve installed Python in your system, here in my case it is “C:\Program Files\Python35-32”.

It must have resolved the error.

To confirm, run this code:

```
“python --version”
```